# Call an expression multiple times in an expression

Tags: c

I'm a student and new to C. One of the questions for my homework reads as follows:

> max is a function that accepts two  int parameters and returns the
>   value of the larger one.   Four  int variables,  population1 , 
>   population2 ,  population3 , and  population4 have already been
>   declared and initialized.   Write an expression (not a statement!)
>   whose value is the largest of  population1 ,  population2 , 
>   population3 , and  population4 by calling  max . (HINT: you will need
>   to call  max three times and you will need to pass the return values
>   of two of those calls as arguments to  max . REMEMBER: write an
>   expression, not a statement.)

I understand the logic of it:

Call the function max with the first two variables, the function will return the larger of the two and then take that value (somehow pass it without assigning to a fifth declared variable) and compare it to the third variable's value. Take the larger of the second pairing (again passing it without the benefit of a  new variable - remember it's an expression, not a statement) and compare it to the forth value. However I haven't been able to write the correct syntax.

Also, understand that this is a 100 level class. So anything higher level will not be accepted for this particular question. No libraries to be #include(d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function calls can be nested. Here's a hint:

```
max(population1, max(...))
```

Can you come up with the correct code for the `...`?

Comment: Thank you, so much for hinting instead of giving me the answer! I figured it out. It should be: max (population1, max(population2, max (population3, population4))) . I was never taught that a function could nest within itself multiple times and the thought never occurred to me.

Answer (score 1):

Well you seem to understand how to do it, and yes the question seems to ask you to not assign returned values to new varibles. You can basically chuck in a max() as a parameter to another max(), and the return of the inner max() will be the int for the outer max() parameter.
Since c is strict, it won't compile unless the return type for the function is the same as the parameter (in this case, both are int, so it's fine)

```
max(2, max(3, 4)); // inner returns 4, which puts 4 into the outer max, and compares 2 to 4
```

Answer (score 0):

A function which returns something different that nothing (`void`) can be used inside an expression freely. An expression is defined recursively since it is made by sub-expressions until you reach terminal symbols (as constants or function calls).

So there is nothing strange in understanding the syntax, a call to `max` is synctatically equivalent to a numeric constant.

```
int x = 5;
int y = max(5,10);
int z = 5 + 10;
int k = max(5,10) + 3;
int j = max(3 + 2, 8);
```

These are all legal. Of course the assignment is just for clarity, as as assignment is a statement, not just an expression anymore.